ckeditor5: Adding a custom style causes unwanted spans to be added when copy paste from google docs
I added a custom style of this type to the ckeditor5 styles list
            style: {
        definitions: [
            {
                name: 'Blue dropcap',
                element: 'span',
                classes: [ 'dropcap' ]
            },
        ]
                },

Since adding this custom style, ckeditor add extra unwanted span tags (without class or attribute) when I copy and paste text from google docs.
For example a simple copy and paste from google docs withtout my custom style output this
<p>
Some text
</p>

When I add my custom style the same copy and paste from google docs output this (please note unwanted extra span added)
<p>
    <span>Some text</span>
</p>

if I try to add this configuration, it has no effect, when copy pasted from google docs extra span (without class or attribute) are also added
htmlSupport: {
            allow: [
                {
            name: 'span',
            classes: [ 'dropcap' ]
        },
        ],
},

if I try to add this configuration extra spans are no longer added but my custom style is grayed out and no longer available
htmlSupport: {
        disallow: [
                {
            name: 'span'
        },
        ],
            allow: [
                {
            name: 'span',
            classes: [ 'dropcap' ]
        },
        ],
},

How can i add my custom style avoiding extra spans being added when copy pasting from google docs?
Thank you very much for your help
